# Use of fseek with stdout

Tags: c

Is it possible to use fseek when the file pointer arg is stdout?

I have tried it in a scenario when I was attempting to overwrite the last "," in a comma separated list with a ")"

e.g.

```
fprintf(stdout, "1,2,3,4,");

fseek(stdout, -1, SEEK_CUR);

fprintf(stdout, ")");
```

to achieve:

1,2,3,4)

as opposed to

1,2,3,4,)

unfortunately I output the latter

Comment: `printf(...)` is equivalent to, and clearer than, `fprintf(stdout, ...)`.

Comment: Regardless of what might work or not, I think it is _a lot_ cleaner to not produce the trailing comma at all, rather than mucking about with the output stream.

Comment: I had reached the same conclusion myself - mucking about with the file pointer position is clearly a can of worms

Comment: I've updated my answer with an alternative solution to the problem of printing a comma-separated list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can successfully use `fseek` on `stdout` *if and only if* `stdout` refers to a seekable stream.

If your program's standard output is going to a terminal or something similar (which is typically the default) or to a pipe, then `fseek` will fail. If it's going to a file because you executed the program with its output redirected, then `fseek` can work as it would for any other file.

Any time you call `fseek`, you should check its return value to see whether it succeeded or failed.

*Assuming* that `stdout` is seekable is probably bad practice, because it's very commonly a bad assumption.

Your goal is to print a sequence of items with `", "` between items, but not before the first or after the last. Neither `fseek` nor printing a `'\b'`is a a good approach for what you're trying to do. Rather than printing the final comma and then trying to erase it, you should print the comma *only* if you haven't just printed the last item in the list. Detecting this can be non-trivial.

But an easier approach is to precede each item with a comma *unless* it's the first one. You can't always tell whether you're printing the last value of a sequence. You *can* always tell whether you're printing the first.

Pseudo-code:

```
bool is_first_item = true
for each item
    if is_first_item
        is_first_item = false
    else
        print ", "
    end if
    print item
end for
```

Comment: Seeking doesn't _necessarily_ fail when `stdout` is redirected to a pipe. Presumably it works (in my brief tests) because the output is still sitting in the buffer.

Answer (score 4):

Using `fseek` on `stdout` is not possible. Instead, you can use the backspace character, `'\b'`, to move the cursor back one space:

```
fprintf(stdout, "1,2,3,4,");

fprintf(stdout, "\b)");
```

Note: this will *only* work if `stdout` points to a terminal, and has *not* been redirected to a file or pipe. Also, if the cursor is currently at the beginning of a line, then this isn't guaranteed to work. In general, there are only a few cases where this will work.

Comment: There's no basis for assuming that `stdout` refers to a terminal, or that printing a `'\b'` to `stdout` will move the cursor. If your program's output is redirected to a file, then you'll just write `"1,2,3,4,\b"` to that file.

Comment: @KeithThompson I added a clarification.

Comment: There are other cases you've neglected. What if `stdout` is going to a pipe?

Comment: @KeithThompson I could argue that I used the term "file" loosely :P but I fixed it regardless

Comment: I've withdrawn my downvote, but it's not at all clear that printing a `'\b'` is a reasonable substitute for an `fseek` call (or that the `fseek` in the question is a reasonable approach even if it works).