# Detect if stdout cursor is at the start of a new line

Tags: c, printf, newline

My program uses various `printf()` statements. Is it possible to determine at any point of the program if the `stdout` cursor is at the start of a new line?

Background: The program uses a custom error routine and I would like to show any error messages on the next blank line. Since the program does not track if the last `printf()` ended with `\n`, the error routine currently starts each message by printing `\n`. This results in two successive `\n` (a blank line) if the last `printf()` also ended with `\n`.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this. It's up to the application to keep track if it's important.

Comment: I can only think of one language that provides a way to do this. Common Lisp has the `FRESH-LINE` function, which outputs a newline unless the last character was a newline.

Comment: For posterity. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329670/use-of-fseek-with-stdout

Comment: The obvious solution would be to write a wrapper function for `printf()` which checks if the format string ends with `\n` and stores that information in a global variable

Comment: one easy fix, ALWAYS end each print statement with '\n'

Answer (score 0):

Please read [linux-cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078725/how-to-get-the-cursor-position-in-a-c-program-using-termcap-without-writing-a-c)  AND [windows-cursor position](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcursorpos?redirectedfrom=MSDN)